# Handle response from a remote server nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, request

I'm making a php POST request from my node js application to a remote server.
The responce from the remote server is a php generated "PDF" file.

I want to save that pdf file into a location.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require("request");


request({
  uri: "http://103.251.43.139/~ksebuser/orumabills/upload/billview/bill_view_click.php",
  method: "POST",
  form: {
    'office':'5617',
    't_consumer-no_0':'1024'
  }
}, function(error, response, body) {
  const data = new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(response));
fs.writeFile('example.txt', data, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The file has been saved!');
});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

> this is the real form
>   http://103.251.43.139/~ksebuser/orumabills/upload/billview/
>
> there I gave the values
>
> OFFICE :  **Adimali(5617) and**  CONSUMER NUMBER : **1024**

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

Comment: how to save as pdf..
it Returning a corrupted pdf  file

Comment: Please edit your question to show exactly what you're doing. Also, read the documentation for `request`, specifically the `encoding` option.

Comment: @robertklep sir if you can please give me  a solution for the issue

Answer (score 1):

The [`request` documentation](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback) states:

> **Note:** if you expect binary data, you should set `encoding: null`.

Since PDF's can contain binary data, you should use that option:

```
request(
  {
    uri:
      "http://103.251.43.139/~ksebuser/orumabills/upload/billview/bill_view_click.php",
    method: "POST",
    form: {
      office: "5617",
      "t_consumer-no_0": "1024"
    },
    encoding : null
  },
  function(error, response, body) {
    fs.writeFile('example.txt', body, err => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("The file has been saved!");
    });
  }
);
```